# SR-71 cool story comment posted as an answer

Tags: discussion, low-quality, specific-answer

This post IMO (and others per the votes/comments and a [flag](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/review/low-quality-posts/31940)) should not be an answer:

https://aviation.stackexchange.com/a/50294 (+6/-2)

It's a cool comment that can be posted as such by linking to one of the dozen web articles on that story.

What do you think?

Example [comment](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/50291/what-is-the-maximum-altitude-atc-would-deal-with/50294#comment131162_50294) I agree with:

> The ground speed anecdote is irrelevant to the question about maximum ATC flight level, and the descend FL600 anecdote only shows that one aircraft once had to ask for it, but doesn't help anything about whether that was within their control. This does not answer the question at all.

Comment: I think that particular answer can be edited to "fill the requirement" merely by pointing out that ATC still provide services to flights above FL600, with the story supporting the claim.

Comment: @kevin - The punchline of the second "story" indicates the ATC didn't have an altitude readout. The reason for saying "story", is there is a chance it's a PR story. There was a thorough post somewhere debunking it -- especially the first story with the speed readout -- by citing the specifications of the ATC units at the time of the story that wouldn't have been able to show the speed. It doesn't matter if I think it's true or not, but simply posting the link the user copied the text from would suffice as a nice-to-share-info in a comment.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Given that the post has received 5 "not an answer" flags, 5 recommended deletions, 1 deletion vote, and moreover, considering, as one comment said, that

> The ground speed anecdote is irrelevant to the question about maximum ATC flight level, and the descend FL600 anecdote only shows that one aircraft once had to ask for it, but doesn't help anything about whether that was within their control. This does not answer the question at all.

the post has been deleted.